# allowing only one instance of page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

i have a question about allowing only one pageinstance in all clientsessions. So if a client ask for the unique page and there is already a session with this page. The client which ask for the page should get a messagebox, which say "This page is already in use"

I read about this problem on forums. Many people say "it's impossible to get out if the client have close the browser (including the unique page)".

Is that true about the serverside?

Is there a way to handling this problem?

Is use Asp.net with Vb.net

i hope anyone understand me. My english is bad.

Comment: Its interesting..will follow this post for different answers..

Comment: The best way I know of to do this would be through a single page app site. Of course, this may not be a practical choice for you due to the work you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with keeping track of whether the current user is still using the page can be managed by having an UpdatePanel with a Timer which then sets an application variable time every 500ms (or whatever interval you want)

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Application["PageLastUsed"] = DateTime.Now;
End Sub
```

and redirect users if the page is in use

```
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - (DateTime)Application["PageLastUsed"];
if (duration.TotalSeconds < 2)
{
    Response.Redirect("InUsePage.aspx");
}
```

See timer info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will try this immediately

Comment: Sorry the code is c#... but the principles are the same. This approach means you don't need to worry about identifying the user, because it never lets more than one user open the page :-)